# Override sourceManaged in the sbt-xjc plugin

Tags: sbt, xjc

I'm using the [sbt-xjc](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-xjc/) plugin to generate my xml classes.

The default value of `sourceManaged` is prepended with `xjc`. I want to remove `xjc`. How should I do that?

Comment: Could [How does one change the source directory in the sbt-xjc plugin for SBT?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8052651/1305344) be of some help?

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding the following to project/build.scala worked:

```
++ Seq(
    sourceManaged in (Compile, SbtXjcPlugin.xjc) <<= sourceManaged
```

The whole file looks like this:

```
import com.github.retronym.sbtxjc.test.BaseScriptedTestBuild
import com.github.retronym.sbtxjc.SbtXjcPlugin
import sbt._
import Keys._

object build extends BaseScriptedTestBuild {
  lazy val root = {

    Project(
     id = "main",
      base = file("."),
      settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ scriptedTestSettings ++ SbtXjcPlugin.xjcSettings  ++ Seq(
        resolvers += "Java Net" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
      )++ Seq(
        sourceManaged in (Compile, SbtXjcPlugin.xjc) <<= sourceManaged
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this config in `build.sbt`, XJC generates the classes directly in `src_managed/main`.

```
SbtXjcPlugin.xjcSettings ++ Seq(
  sources in (Compile, xjc) <<= baseDirectory map (_ / "xsd" ** "*.xsd" get),
  sourceManaged in (Compile, xjc) <<= sourceManaged / "main"
)
```

XJC will look for xsd files in `/xsd` and output the generated classes in `/target/scala-2.x/src_managed/main`

Comment: Can you give more details, `SbtXjcPlugin.xjcSettings` is not found but

`xjcSettings ++ Seq(...)` works but when i launch xjc task it can't find any xsd

Comment: This solution works but not with `main` directory but with a subdirectory `main/xsd` :
````
sourceManaged in (Compile, SbtXjcPlugin.xjc) <<= sourceManaged / "main/xsd"
````